# sorting multiple formats of dates (strings)? Python

Tags: python, date, sorting, datetime, format

I have a list of multiple formats of dates (strings), and I would like to sort format them all to be the same, and sort them by date,  I have worked out a complicated way of making this work. but I am trying to clean up my code a bit, and Im under the assumption that there is a much simpler way of doing it.

Nov 4, 2020

Nov 23, 2020

2020-11-12 yyyy-mm-dd

2020-11-10

11/02/2020  mm/dd/yyyy

11/18/2020

THANKS!

Comment: in a date like `11/02/2020`, is it month or day first? any specific language?

Comment: month, day, year. python.  ill edit the post. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the formats are as "standard" as this, you can make use of [dateutil's parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

```
from dateutil import parser

l = ["Nov 4, 2020", "Nov 23, 2020", "2020-11-12", "2020-11-10", "11/02/2020", "11/18/2020"]

dates = sorted(map(parser.parse, l))
# [datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 10, 0, 0),
# ...]

# to common format: e.g.
dates_formatted = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in dates] # == d.date().isoformat()
# ['2020-11-02',
#  '2020-11-04',
#  '2020-11-10',
#  ...]
```